# Embedded .Json file cannot be located after I renamed the project

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I changed the name of my project and when I run it it runs fine but when it reaches the part where it does validation from json I get the following error:

> Cannot find embedded resource: hot.json

but when I change the name back to the original name the error goes away. I have tried deleting the old one and then added another json file with different name and I still got the same error.

here is where the error is occurring in my code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        using (
            var stream =
                assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
                    $"HotStuff.TestResources.Languages.{language}.json"))
        {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot find embedded resource: {language}.json");

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd()).ToObject<JToken>();
                var value = json.SelectToken(key.Replace(" ", "-"));
                return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you renamed every instance of your project name. Easiest way is to open the folder in VS Code/Sublime and do a global search for the old name of the project. My best guess is that something wasn't renamed in the csproj file.

Comment: If you renamed your project, make sure you make the necessary changes to `HotStuff.TestResources.Languages` as per your new assembly name and namespaces (if changed)

Comment: Thanks guys! The issue was in my csproj